# How to get the Swagger schema for a specific version of a Swagger API?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I know I can add a `/v3/api-docs/` to the end of my APIs endpoint to get a JSON representation of my APIs schema.

Is there a way to get the schema for a specific version of the API?

Comment: This functionality is specific to your server-side framework. What server/framework/library do you use for your API?

Comment: We are using the SpringDoc Library to generate our OpenAPI/Swagger UI in our Java Springboot Application

Comment: What you're looking for is API versioning. Refer to the migration guide [here](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox) on how to define the API groups in Springdoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, we have a versioned API.

The below URI was our entire JSON schema including all API versions.

```
.../v3/api-docs
```

But, the below URI was scoped only to a specific API version.

```
.../v3/api-docs/v2-tool
```

The `v2-tool` corresponds to a namespace specific to our code.